# how to pass a frame buffer from C to Python using OpenCV

Tags: python, c, opencv

I had an image processing function (IMP) written in Python using OpenCV lib.

Now I would like to call IMP from C code:

```
#include "/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h"
int main()
{
  PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFun, *pValue, main_module;

 // Initialize the Python Interpreter
 Py_Initialize();
 // Build the name object
 pName = PyString_FromString("test");
 if(pName)printf("OK\n");

 // Load the module object
 pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

  // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
  pFun = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "IMP");

  if (PyCallable_Check(pFun)) 
  {
    //PyObject_CallObject(pFun, NULL);
     PyObject_CallFunction(pFun,"o",framebuffer);
  } 
  else 
  {
     PyErr_Print();
  }

   // Clean up
   Py_DECREF(pModule);
   Py_DECREF(pName);
   Py_DECREF(pFun);
   // Finish the Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

How do I prepare "framebuffer" to pass into my IMP python function?

could anyone help to show me an example image packaged in an object understood by CV2 and pass it to IMP using the above example C code? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: what is your 'IMP' doing ? it's probably far easier, porting that to c++ instead.

Comment: it just tries to recognize certain features and return yes or no. Since it is going run in an embedded system, so I am using C as the target code, yet CV2 C interfaces are deprecated so I would call my Python code directly for development. If it is proven, then I might translate it to C++ in the future and have C call to the C++ dll later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what I need: just create a template "framebuffer" in my test.py:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

framebuffer = cv2.imread('pic.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

def IMP(p):
  print "I am here!"
  print "image.shape h,w,d=",p.shape
  cv2.imshow("picture",p)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and then in my test.c, I grep the "framebuffer" from pDict for further manipulation then call IMP:

```
#include "/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h"
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

int main()
{
  PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFun, *pValue, *pArgs, *pFB;
  int i,j;

  // Initialize the Python Interpreter
  Py_Initialize();

 // Build the name object
    pName = PyString_FromString("test");
    if(pName)printf("OK\n");

    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    // pDict is a borrowed reference 
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

    // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
    pFun = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "IMP");
    pFB =  PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "framebuffer");
    if (pFB != NULL)
       printf("got the framebuffer as pFB!\n");
       //copy a new framebuffer into pFB here!!!
       uint8_t *ptr;
       ptr = PyArray_DATA(pFB);
       int col,row,color;
       int NCOL = 0, NROW = 0, NCLR = 0;
       int ndim=0;

       ndim = PyArray_NDIM(pFB);
       NROW = PyArray_DIM(pFB,0);
       NCOL = PyArray_DIM(pFB,1);
       NCLR = PyArray_DIM(pFB,2);

       for (row=0;row<NROW;row++)
          for (col=0;col<NCOL;col++)
             for (color=0;color<NCLR;color++)
             {
                 *ptr = pixel_value; //copy your framebuffer pixel value to pFB!!!
                 ptr++;
             }


    pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs,0,pFB);

    if (PyCallable_Check(pFun)) 
    {
       PyObject_CallObject(pFun, pArgs); //call python IMP with updated framebuffer!!!
    } 
    else 
    {
       PyErr_Print();
    }

    // Clean up
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    //Py_DECREF(pDict); //do not decref on pDict because it is borrowed ref, otherwise it will crash Py_Finalize()!!!
    //Py_DECREF(pArgs);
    //Py_DECREF(pFun);
    //Py_DECREF(pFB);

    // Finish the Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

That's it!